# Convexity of the ratio of the standard normal PDF by its CDF

Tags: probability, convex-analysis

Is there some way to show that the following function $\psi$ is concave or convex? Here, $\phi$ and $\mathbf{\Phi}$ are the standard normal PDF and CDF, respectively.

$$\psi\left(u\right)=u+\frac{\phi\left(u\right)}{\Phi\left(u\right)}$$

There is of course the calculus way, but the resulting second derivative is fairly complex. Hence, please advice if there is any alternate way or some simplification using the derivative approach itself that can establish this.

Comment: Did, could you please elaborate your approach and thinking?

Comment: Sure -- but you first: what did you do to check the convexity/concavity of psi?

Comment: I used calculus and ended up with a complex expression, a small headache and no result .. :-) I must mention that the function I would be finally interested in would be like this: $ \alpha x\psi\left(\beta x\right)+\alpha\left(y-x\right)\psi\left\{ \beta\left(y-x\right)\right\}  $. Here, $y>0$, $\alpha>0$ and $\beta>0$. Would be keen to hear your thoughts / suggestions?

Comment: The computation of $\psi''$ is not that horrible if one uses repeatedly that $\varphi'(u)=-u\varphi(u)$ and $\Phi'=\varphi$. The result is a fraction with denominator $\Phi^3>0$ while the numerator is $>0$ when $u\to+\infty$ and $<0$ at $u=0$ (provided I made no mistake in my computations). This allows to conclude.

Comment: Thanks much appreciated. I did not use  φ′(u)=−uφ(u). Would you then say, it is convex and concave over different regions?

Comment: PDF has two inflection points, so check three regions. CDF has one inflection point, so check two regions.

Comment: Actually I did make a mistake in my computation and $\psi''$ seems to be positive everywhere. Unless I am mistaken (bis), one should prove that $$2\varphi^2(u)+3u\varphi(u)\Phi(u)+(u^2-1)\Phi^2(u)>0.$$

Comment: @Did, I got a similar expression as above, Is there a way to show that this is positive without a numerical approach that you use below in the answer? Much appreciative of all the answers from everyone this far.

Comment: It seems you are interested in $u>0$ only. Then consider $$K(u)=2\varphi^2(u)+3u\varphi(u)\Phi(u)+(u^2-1)\Phi^2(u).$$ For $u\geqslant1$, $K(u)\gt0$. Furthermore, $K(0)=\frac1\pi-\frac14>0$ and, for $u$ in $(0,1)$, $$K'(u)=u(2\Phi^2(u)-\phi^2(u))+(1-u^2)\varphi(u)\Phi(u)\geqslant uL(u),$$ where $L(u)=2\Phi^2(u)-\varphi^2(u)$. Now, $\Phi(u)\geqslant\frac12$ and $\varphi^2(u)\leqslant\frac1{2\pi}$ hence $L(u)\geqslant\frac12-\frac1{2\pi}>0$, hence $K(u)\geqslant K(0)$ for every $u$ in $(0,1)$, QED.

Comment: @Did … Thanks for your extremely helpful and clear answers. Now suppose, $G\left(x\right)=x\frac{\phi\left(x\right)}{\Phi\left(x\right)}$. Would this function $G\left(x\right)$ be convex?

Comment: New problem? Then ask new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This graph of the various functions should help demonstrate the convexity visually. Hope this helps. Thanks for all the pointers and useful suggestions.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a numerical check that indeed $\varphi/\Phi$ is convex because the second derivative is positive everywhere (note that a mathematical proof of the convexity on $(0,+\infty)$ is in the comments):

[image]